# How can I make divs float beside & down each others?

Tags: css, html, css-float

http://oi49.tinypic.com/2qithg4.jpg *(example is a jpg img)*

As You can see in the example; the boxes (after floating) gets a white space under it in order to make a room for an equal row of divs
but I wanna float all of 'em to fill the gaps.. any suggestions?

That's what I wanna do *(example is a jpg img)*

http://oi47.tinypic.com/2nixr2x.jpg

Thanks in advance.

edit// Showing Alex some code :)

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
<div id="featured"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div style="width:310px; height:18px; margin:0 0 10px; padding:98px 0; text-align:center; float:left; display: block; background: #ffffcc;">Ad Space</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content { }
#featured { width:630px; float:right; height:214px; margin:0 10px 10px 0; }
.box { float:left; width:310px; margin:0 10px 10px 0; height:400px; }
```

Comment: I would suggest using a table instead of divs.

Comment: Can you post what you already have in place?

Comment: @Teak the examples or not tabular data so suggesting s table for layouting is bad

Comment: You might want to have a look at [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), although you can most lively achieve what you want to do with CSS alone.

Comment: @JamWaffles ya and I wanna do it with pure css :(

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I guess I could have been more clear, however it looks to me like he could make a three column, one row table that would solve the problem. (I notice now that the div at the top right might cause problems)

Comment: Guys I know that I can do it by positioning each box but I will make it for a dynamic content so I can't do it manually I need to do something automatically make boxes behave like the example.

Comment: Could you put each of the 3 boxes inside one div? If you then set those outer divs to `overflow: hidden;` it would work :)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question had been asked before: [Vertical alignment of float:left div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445960/vertical-alignment-of-floatleft-divs), though no proper solutions were presented. As far as I guess doing it with pure CSS for a dynamic content would be difficult, so I would suggest to use [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for this task.

**For a pure CSS approach, I guess it can be done using `CSS3 columns` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847460/how-can-i-make-a-float-top-with-css).**